# How to create a swipeable tablayout like spendee app

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I would like to know whether we can create a swipeable tablayout similar like the below picture that is taking the dates from sqlite database and showing it in tablayout.can anyone tell me is there any examples in which i can show the dates in tablayouts.I have give the tablayout with static names but i want to create it in dynamic.

[image]

Comment: What you have tried ?? Post that code ..

Comment: @Ironman I have created a tablayout with viewpager with static data given in arraylist

Comment: Check [this](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Use TabLayout and ViewPager sample code

```
  <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/mydriverveh_tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
       />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

then create Viewpager adapter extends with FragmentPagerAdapter  and add fragments to adapter

Answer (score 0):

Thats is called *`scrollable`* tabs

create a new activity with ViewPager Tabs 
and in TabLayout set its mode to Scrollable.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/tabs"
app:tabMode="scrollable"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

refer this page for creating Tab activity with viewgager.[TabLayout with viewPager](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-tablayout-example-using-viewpager-fragments/)